# How to get issuer certificate public key using crypto api

Tags: windows, ssl, cryptography, certificate, digital-signature

I need to get the issuer certificate public key for a given certificate (which I receive).

I read certificate byte and able to get `PCCERT_CONTEXT` using `CertCreateCertificateContext()` for leaf certificate.

`PCCERT_CONTEXT->pCertInfo->SubjectPublicKeyInfo` give me the leaf certificate public key, But I am not able to find a way to get issuer certificate details.

Comment: A cert doesn't know what the public key of it's issuer is.  You'd need to build a chain (CertGetCertificateChain) and work with the issuer cert.

Comment: CertGetCertificateChain gives CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT which contains CERT_TRUST_STATUS  which is overall validation status. My question is how would I get the issuer PCCERT_CONTEXT  from this?

Comment: There is a `CertGetIssuerCertificateFromStore` method. If you have a PFX/P12 then you probably need to open it as a store, not as a single certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Issuer public key can only be obtained from issuer cert and this is not present in leaf cert(received cert)(thanks bartonjs)
The solution I have is to build full chain get reach to the signer to get the key or have the issuer certificate obtained from another source (if possible). In my case, I have another source so I am able to get it. thanks for the guidance.